# Unable to get Selenium Web Driver running with Java

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java

I tried running the following code to start running Selenium WebDriver on Java, using the following code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.*;
public class Runner 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        WebDriver driver;
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
        try
        {/// Exception thrown on initElements

            GoogleSearchPage page1 = PageFactory.initElements(driver, GoogleSearchPage.class);


            page1.SearchFor("hu ha 123");
        }
        catch(Exception excp)
        {
            System.out.println(excp.toString());
        }
        driver.quit();
    }

}

class GoogleSearchPage
{
    @FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "q")
    public WebElement searchbox;

    public void SearchFor(String Text)
    {
        searchbox.sendKeys(Text);
        searchbox.submit();
    }
}
```

I get the exception 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory can not access a member of class moronicpackage.GoogleSearchPage with modifiers ""

Any ideas?

Comment: The exception was being thrown because of incorrect documentation in the Selenium reference. I used the following syntax for initialization of the page and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling PageFactory.initElements incorrectly.  The second argument needed to be a GoogleSearchPage instance rather than the GoogleSearchPage class object.  The main method needed to look like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    WebDriver driver;
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
    try
    {
        GoogleSearchPage page1 = new GoogleSearchPage();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, page1);        
        page1.SearchFor("hu ha 123");
    }
    catch(Exception excp)
    {
        System.out.println(excp.toString());
    }

    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have added the response as a comment to the answer too.

Comment: Ashish, can you to mark this answer as the best one? Just click the checkmark next to the vote count.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with documentation. Need to specify page object classes as public classes.So moving GoogleSearchPage to different file and specifying it as public class should work fine. the way suggested here is also correct but is just an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your GoogleSearchPage class public.  Instead of this:

```
class GoogleSearchPage
```

do this:

```
public class GoogleSearchPage
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that did not make any difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Create_User {
    WebDriver driver;

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities); 
    driver.get(getProperty("www.google.co.in"));
}
```

Comment: Do this one for internet explorer.its working fine